# Fail to inverse the Piecewise function embedded in a NDSolveValue

Tags: performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization, fitting, finite-element-method, inverse

I am trying to estimate a function consisting of a Piecewise function that included in a FEM solver.

I firstly developed my mesh for the FEM model based on @Tim Laska's work. The code is shown as

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
(*Define Some Helper Functions For Structured Quad Mesh*)
pointsToMesh[data_] := 
  MeshRegion[Transpose[{data}], 
   Line@Table[{i, i + 1}, {i, Length[data] - 1}]];
unitMeshGrowth[n_, r_] := 
 Table[(r^(j/(-1 + n)) - 1.)/(r - 1.), {j, 0, n - 1}]
unitMeshGrowth2Sided[nhalf_, r_] := (1 + Union[-Reverse@#, #])/2 &@
  unitMeshGrowth[nhalf, r]
meshGrowth[x0_, xf_, n_, r_] := (xf - x0) unitMeshGrowth[n, r] + x0
firstElmHeight[x0_, xf_, n_, r_] := 
 Abs@First@Differences@meshGrowth[x0, xf, n, r]
lastElmHeight[x0_, xf_, n_, r_] := 
 Abs@Last@Differences@meshGrowth[x0, xf, n, r]
findGrowthRate[x0_, xf_, n_, fElm_] := 
 Quiet@Abs@
   FindRoot[firstElmHeight[x0, xf, n, r] - fElm, {r, 1.0001, 100000}, 
     Method -> "Brent"][[1, 2]]
meshGrowthByElm[x0_, xf_, n_, fElm_] := 
 N@Sort@Chop@meshGrowth[x0, xf, n, findGrowthRate[x0, xf, n, fElm]]
meshGrowthByElmSym[x0_, xf_, n_, fElm_] := 
 With[{mid = Mean[{x0, xf}]}, 
  Union[meshGrowthByElm[mid, x0, n, fElm], 
   meshGrowthByElm[mid, xf, n, fElm]]]
reflectRight[pts_] := 
 With[{rt = ReflectionTransform[{1}, {Last@pts}]}, 
  Union[pts, Flatten[rt /@ Partition[pts, 1]]]]
reflectLeft[pts_] := 
 With[{rt = ReflectionTransform[{-1}, {First@pts}]}, 
  Union[pts, Flatten[rt /@ Partition[pts, 1]]]]
extendMesh[mesh_, newmesh_] := Union[mesh, Max@mesh + newmesh]
uniformPatch[p1_, p2_, \[Rho]_] := 
  With[{d = p2 - p1}, Subdivide[0, d, 2 + Ceiling[d \[Rho]]]];
meshGrowthByElm0[len_, n_, fElm_] := meshGrowthByElm[0, len, n, fElm]
flipSegment[l_] := (#1 - #2) & @@ {First[#], #} &@Reverse[l]; sz1 = 
 meshGrowthByElm[0, 500, 100, 0.1];
rz = pointsToMesh@sz1
crd = MeshCoordinates[rz];
mesh = ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> crd];
```

[image]

Then, I evaluate the FEM model with all parameters known to generate a synthetic data:

```
Do[q[i] = 1./(Sqrt[i]*500.), {i, 1, Length@sz1}];
f[i_] := q[i]
g[func_Symbol, x_] := 
 Piecewise[
  Table[{func[i], sz1[[i]] < x < sz1[[i + 1]]}, {i, 1, 
    Length@sz1 - 1}], 0]
Q = g[f, x];
Ca = 10^6; λ = 2.5;
T = NDSolveValue[{Ca*D[hf[x,t],t] == λ*D[hf[x,t],x,x] - Q*D[hf[x,t],x,x],
    hf[x, 0] == 13., hf[0, t] == 20.
    }, hf, x ∈ mesh, {t, 0, 86400*365}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
       "LinearSolveMethod" -> {"Pardiso"}}}];
```

And I generate the synthetic data by adding some "noise":

```
   Data = {#, T[#, 86400*20]} & /@ 
  Range[1, 10, 
   0.25]; Datanoise = {#, 
    T[#, 86400*20] (1 + 
       0.01*RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 1][[1]])} & /@ 
  Range[1, 10, 0.25];

Show[ListLinePlot[Data, PlotRange -> All], 
 ListPlot[Datanoise, PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image]

After that, I clear the value used in q and try to use the FindFit function to inverses q[1], q[2]... For example:

```
Clear[q]; Fitting = 
 FindFit[Datanoise, T[x, 86400*20], 
  Table[{q[i], 1/(Sqrt[i]*500.)}, {i, 1, g[f, All][[1, -1, 1, 1]]}], x, 
  Method -> "LevenbergMarquardt", AccuracyGoal -> 60, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 60, WorkingPrecision -> Automatic, 
  MaxIterations -> 100]
```

But MMA warn me this one
[image]
And give a wrong results

```
Show[ListPlot[Fitting[[All, 2]]], 
 ListLinePlot[Table[1/(Sqrt[i]*1000.), {i, 1, g[f, 10][[1]]}]]]
```

[image]

It seems the results would not be converged when I try to apply another methods like NMinimize or coupled with DifferentialEvolution and post process with LevenbergMarquardt to fit the data.

Later, I think we need to built another numerical solver to delay the q[1]...

```
Clear[q]; f[i_] := q[i]
g[func_Symbol, x_] := 
 Piecewise[
  Table[{func[i], sz1[[i]] < x < sz1[[i + 1]]}, {i, 1, 
    Length@sz1 - 1}], 0]
Q = g[f, x]; 
model[Q_?NumberQ] := Module[{T, x, t}, T = NDSolveValue[{Ca*D[hf[x,t],t] == λ*D[hf[x,t],x,x] - Q*D[hf[x,t],x,x],
        hf[x, 0] == 13., hf[0, t] == 20.
        }, hf, x ∈ mesh, {t, 0, 86400*365}, 
       Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
         "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
           "LinearSolveMethod" -> {"Pardiso"}}}]]
```

Then, run the code again:

```
Fitting = 
 FindFit[Datanoise, model[Q][x, 86400*20], 
  Table[{q[i], 1/(Sqrt[i]*500.)}, {i, 1, Length@g[f, All][[1, -1, 1, 1]]}], x]
```

And the code is running perpetually...

**Update**
I rewrite the code like this

```
    a2 = sz1[[#]] <= x < sz1[[# + 1]] & /@ Range[1, Length@sz1 - 1]; a1 = 
 Symbol["q" <> ToString[#]] & /@ Range[1, Length@a2]; 
qn[x_] = Piecewise[Transpose@{a1, a2}]; FindFit[Datanoise, 
 NDSolveValue[{Ca*D[hf[x, t], t] == \[Lambda]*D[hf[x, t], x, x] - 
      qn[x]*D[hf[x, t], x, x], hf[x, 0] == 13., hf[0, t] == 20.}, hf, 
   x ∈ mesh, {t, 0, 86400*365}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
       "LinearSolveMethod" -> {"Pardiso"}}}][x, 86400*20], a1,x, 
 Method -> "LevenbergMarquardt", AccuracyGoal -> 60, 
 PrecisionGoal -> 60, WorkingPrecision -> Automatic, 
 MaxIterations -> 100]
```

It still doesn't work. How to make q1, q2, ... estimable via FindFit?

Comment: I couldn't evaluate your code and get an error "NDSolveValue::femnr: x\[Element]ToElementMesh[Coordinates->{{0.},{0.1},{0.20592},{0.31811},{0.436941},{0.562807},{0.696125},{0.837334},{0.986902},{1.14533},<<90>>}] is not a valid region specification."

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Sorry, something wrong in the code. I fina update the code.

Comment: Dear @UlrichNeumann, I updated the code. Could you evaluate it without errors?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't run. I changed the mesh definition to `ToElementMesh[crt]` ...

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Ah! So the ToElementMesh function does not properly work?